# Best_in_place display_with not finding helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, best-in-place

There's not a lot of documentation as to how to use the display_with option in Best  In place, but I'm trying to get Best_in_Place to display dates in condensed form, (mm/dd/yyyy).
My db (sqlserver) has the dates stored in datetime format, and I use this command to display the field:

```
<%= best_in_place(@production, :budget_approval_internal,  type: :date, :nil => "[Not    set]")  %>
```

When clicked the gem works as expected, putting up a calendar control to select the date, and then displaying it in short form.  But when I press refresh I get a date that looks like:

```
 2013-12-04 00:00:00 UTC
```

So I thought I could use the :display_with option to have use a helper that looks like this:

```
def format_date(my_date)
   my_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
end
```

I put this in the application_helper.rb module and then tried this:

```
 <%= best_in_place(@production, :budget_approval_internal,  type: :date, :display_with => :format_date, :nil => "[Not    set]")  %>
```

but I get an error in saying:

"can't find helper format_date.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you should `include ApplicationHelper` in your controller or add the method to the appropriate helper file.
Edit : You need to open the ActionView::Base class and add your method

```
module ActionView  
    class Base  
        def format_date(rec)  
            rec.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')  
        end  
    end  
end
```

Comment: Nope, I believe ApplicationHelper is included automatically in all controllers, but in any event it didn't help. interestingly, if I just put <%= format_date(@production.budget_approval_internal) %> in the view, it works fine.   I'm not sure how format_date is supposed to get the parameter from :display_with, but I'm assuming that's part of the best_in_place magic.

Comment: It looks like it only accepts helpers from the ActionView module. In lib/best_in_place/helper.rb there's a check `ViewHelpers.respond_to?(opts[:display_with])`. And the ViewHelpers is created like this `BestInPlace::ViewHelpers = ActionView::Base.new`

Comment: So is there a way to mix in this function into the ActionView module somehow?

Comment: Good idea. Try adding this after the ApplicationHelper module : `module ActionView
    class Base
        def format_date(rec)
            rec.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        end
    end
end
`

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem and used a small snippet from the pull requests of best_in_place done by zubin.

> `<%= in_place_edit(@term, :starts_on, display_with: lambda { |dt| ldt(dt) }, html_attrs: {datepicker: "true"}) %>`

here the ldt is the method which takes a date object and converts to format of my desire.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can override the setter method for `budget_approval_internal` of your production model. This is not the best solution but if you are using best_in_place in this model only then it ok.

```
class Production
  def budget_approval_internal
    read_attribute(:budget_approval_internal).strftime("dd/mm/YY")
  end
end
```

Comment: I thought of that but it doesn't really addres the problem as to why I can't :display_with to work.  I've got about 30 date fields in the model I'd have to deal with, and it seems like a lot of unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem myself. For a simple formatting method like you have, you should just use `:display_as` instead of `:display_with`.

Your b_i_p code in the view would use `:display_as => format_date`.

Then put the `format_date` method in your model. Remove the argument and rewrite the method as follows:

```
def format_date
   self.my_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
end
```

No need to mess around with ApplicationHelper.